# Thin set or spackle to fill home before tiling

Tags: tiling, patching-drywall, backsplash

I am preparing a drywall wall for a tile backslash in a kitchen.  There is a hole that needs to be fixed behind the faucet.  Is it better to use spackle or thin set, since it would be in a place where there could potentially be a risk of water getting behind the tile at some point.

Comment: How large is the hole?

Comment: Why waste $ on thinset , it is not the correct product for use with drywall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drywall compound is the correct material to patch drywall with.  I'm curious why you aren't tiling to a fiber cement product, and suggest using a waterproofing membrane like Hydroban if you are really worried about water infiltration - https://www.google.com/search?q=hydro+ban&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLspa0_7HZAhVnp1kKHbQ9DyYQsxgIKw&biw=1760&bih=839 is very easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  I have never heard of hydroban before and will look into it.  I used cement board when I redid the bathrooms in my house, but I never even thought about it for the kitchen walls.  The cabinets and counter tops are already in, so probably too late to do it now.  For future reference, though, how would that affect hanging cabinets?  For instance, I had a 9 inch cabinet that was not over a stud and had to be mounted with toggle bolts.  Would cement board hold up to toggle bolts.  I'm not a contractor.  Just a Diy guy, so I'm sorry if my question seems stupid.

Comment: i wouldn't mount cabinets to anything but wood/metal stud or solid blocking. I think cement board is only a requirement in a shower/bath and that in the kitchen you will be Ok without it - although it's the material i would have used.  the hydroban or similar waterproofing product will go a long way in terms of protecting it.